# Cruzar dois dataframes diferentes, com número de linhas diferentes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, ciência-de-dados

Tenho o seguinte dataset

```
df.head()
```

[image: df.head]

Na coluna Grau instrução, tenho os valores dos índices de cada grau de instrução, apresentados na tabela abaixo:

```
Grau_Instr_Bibl = {'Categoria': ['Analfabeto', 'Até 5ª Incompleto', '5ª Completo Fundamental', '6ª a 9ª Fundamental', 'Fundamental Completo', 'Médio Incompleto', 'Médio Completo', 'Superior Incompleto', 'Superior Completo', 'MESTRADO', 'DOUTORADO', 'IGNORADO'],
                   'Valores na fonte': ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','-1']
                  }
Grau_Instr_Bibli = pd.DataFrame(data=Grau_Instr_Bibl)
Grau_Instr_Bibli
```

[image: Biblioteca Instruçao]

Eu gostaria de substituir os "Valores na fonte" pelo nome da categoria em uma nova coluna.

Eu tentei fazer um `for`, mas **sem sucesso**:

```
for i in range(0, df.shape[0]):
   if df.at[i, "Grau Instrução"] == Grau_Instr_Bibli['Valores na fonte']:
     df['GrauNovo'] = df.append(df['Grau Instrução'].loc[[i]])
```

Existe um modo mais fácil de comparar dois datasets com números de linhas diferentes ou só com um laço `for`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode resolver isso usando a função `.map()` passando uma Series para ela, desta forma:

```
dataset_original = pd.DataFrame({'Grau de instrucao': ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','-1']})

s = Grau_Instr_Bibli.set_index('Valores na fonte')['Categoria']

dataset_original['GrauNovo'] = dataset_original['Grau de instrucao'].map(s)

#saida do dataset_original
    Grau de instrucao   GrauNovo
0   1                   Analfabeto
1   2                   Até 5ª Incompleto
2   3                   5ª Completo Fundamental
3   4                   6ª a 9ª Fundamental
4   5                   Fundamental Completo
5   6                   Médio Incompleto
6   7                   Médio Completo
7   8                   Superior Incompleto
8   9                   Superior Completo
9   10                  MESTRADO
10  11                  DOUTORADO
11  -1                  IGNORADO
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda!
Mas precisei modificar para adequar ao meu problema, como a coluna `df[Grau Instrução]` do dataframe original era do tipo int64, tive que adequar a ideia do s, da seguinte forma:

`s = {1: 'Analfabeto', 2: 'Até 5ª Incompleto', 3: '5ª Completo Fundamental', 4: '6ª a 9ª Fundamental', 5: 'Fundamental Completo', 6: 'Médio Incompleto', 7: 'Médio Completo', 8: 'Superior Incompleto', 9: 'Superior Completo', 10: 'MESTRADO', 11: 'DOUTORADO', -1: 'IGNORADO'}` _colocando os índices como int, dentro da variavel s_ deste modo o método funcionou! 
Muito obrigado a todos!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o replace com um dicionário.

Importando o pacote:

```
import pandas as pd
```

Criando o primeiro data frame:

```
Grau_Instr_Bibl = {'Categoria': ['Analfabeto', 'Até 5ª Incompleto', '5ª Completo Fundamental', '6ª a 9ª Fundamental', 'Fundamental Completo', 'Médio Incompleto', 'Médio Completo', 'Superior Incompleto', 'Superior Completo', 'MESTRADO', 'DOUTORADO', 'IGNORADO'],
                   'Valores na fonte': ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','-1']
                  }
Grau_Instr_Bibli = pd.DataFrame(data=Grau_Instr_Bibl)
```

Simulando seu arquivo 'fonte':

```
fonte = pd.DataFrame({'Valores na fonte': ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','-1']})
```

Aqui criamos o dicionário com chave e valores do `Grau_Instr_Bibli`, e substituímos no `fonte`:

```
fonte.replace(Grau_Instr_Bibli.set_index('Valores na fonte').to_dict()['Categoria'], inplace = True)
```

Entrada:

```
    Valores na fonte
0   1
1   2
2   3
3   4
4   5
5   6
6   7
7   8
8   9
9   10
10  11
11  -1
```

Saída:

```
    Valores na fonte
0   Analfabeto
1   Até 5ª Incompleto
2   5ª Completo Fundamental
3   6ª a 9ª Fundamental
4   Fundamental Completo
5   Médio Incompleto
6   Médio Completo
7   Superior Incompleto
8   Superior Completo
9   MESTRADO
10  DOUTORADO
11  IGNORADO
```

---

Criando uma nova coluna:

```
fonte['Nova coluna'] = fonte.replace(Grau_Instr_Bibli.set_index('Valores na fonte').to_dict()['Categoria'])
```

*Note que removi o `inplace = True`*

Saída:

```
    Valores na fonte    Nova coluna
0           1           Analfabeto
1           2           Até 5ª Incompleto
2           3           5ª Completo Fundamental
3           4           6ª a 9ª Fundamental
4           5           Fundamental Completo
5           6           Médio Incompleto
6           7           Médio Completo
7           8           Superior Incompleto
8           9           Superior Completo
9          10           MESTRADO
10         11           DOUTORADO
11         -1           IGNORADO
```

---

Código completo:

```
import pandas as pd

Grau_Instr_Bibl = {'Categoria': ['Analfabeto', 'Até 5ª Incompleto', '5ª Completo Fundamental', '6ª a 9ª Fundamental', 'Fundamental Completo', 'Médio Incompleto', 'Médio Completo', 'Superior Incompleto', 'Superior Completo', 'MESTRADO', 'DOUTORADO', 'IGNORADO'],
                   'Valores na fonte': ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','-1']}

Grau_Instr_Bibli = pd.DataFrame(data=Grau_Instr_Bibl)

fonte = pd.DataFrame({'Valores na fonte': ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','-1']})

fonte['Nova coluna'] = fonte.replace(Grau_Instr_Bibli.set_index('Valores na fonte').to_dict()['Categoria'])
```

Comment: Eu não me expressei bem, eu precisaria substituir isso, no primeiro dataset

```
df['Grau_TOP'] = df['Grau Instrução'].replace(Grau_Instr_Bibli.set_index('Valores na fonte').to_dict()df['Grau Instrução'], inplace = True)
df['Grau_TOP']

```

Mas não deu certo. (E muito obrigado pela resposta, to tentando adaptar pro meu problema)

Comment: pra criar em uma nova coluna você poderia fazer: `fonte['Nova coluna'] = fonte.replace(Grau_Instr_Bibli.set_index('Valores na fonte').to_dict()['Categoria'])`